# What does "No matching private key for certificate" mean for openssh certificate-signed host keys?

Tags: ssh, certificate-authority

I'm trying to set up OpenSSH host certificates to cut down on the effort of managing ssh_known_hosts as hosts come and go at my site.  I created a SSH key pair to serve as the CA key.  I then set up Ansible to sign a host key with the CA using the openssh_cert module, add HostCertificate /path/to/signed_host_key to sshd_config, and reload sshd.

However, after I added the certificate key to ssh_known_hosts, I still get prompted to confirm the authenticity of the host.  When I log in to the host and check the log, I see this error message:

```
error: No matching private key for certificate
```

What does that error message mean in the context of certificate signed keys? Signing only creates a cert-signed public key, and I know I'm not supposed to upload the CA private key to the host.

I searched for that error message, and got a bunch of generic discussions about creating keys or creating SSH certificates, or listings of the openssh source code if I searched with quotes around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of certificate signed host keys, that error message means that the signed host key doesn't match the corresponding host key.  For example, if you generate a signed host key then fully recreate the host (creating a new host key), but still try to use the signed host key created against the old version of the host.

As of this writing, the Ansible openssh_cert module [doesn't notice](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/54655) if the signing key or host key has changed.  That means if you sign a host key and then the host key changes, openssh_cert will **not** notice.  You have to `force: yes` to make it regenerate the signed host key against the updated host key.

(Self answering so that others will find this more easily. I eventually noticed that the host key files were newer than the signed host key files and figured out that openssh_cert wasn't regenerating the signed host key when the host key changed.)